# Unix: Increment date column by one day in csv file

Tags: unix, date, sed

Help needed. I want to increment Date (which is a string) column in csv by one day.
e.g. (Date Format yyyy-MM-dd)

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
ABC,001,1900-01-01
XYZ,002,2000-01-01
```

Expected OutPut

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
ABC,001,1900-01-02
XYZ,002,2000-01-02
```

Comment: `sed` doesn't know about dates. You will have to use a more powerful language like Python.

Comment: Sometimes you need to increment the month and sometimes the year, and months are different length, and there are loop years.. it's a suicide mission for `sed`.

Comment: This is not job for sed. before I post an answer, I have to know, is the year `1900` really in your file? or you just made it as example. If your earliest date is after `1902`, I can post an answer. with awk

Comment: Hint: given a date, you can +1 day with `date -d'1900-01-01 +1 day'`

Comment: @fedorqui did you try that line?

Comment: Of course, @Kent: `$ date -d'1900-01-01 +1 day'
Tue Jan  2 00:00:00 AMT 1900`

Comment: not working here. I guess overflow problem.

Comment: @fedorqui you have 64bit OS, don't u?

Comment: Yes, @Kent. So in fact my hint is not useful as not applicable to all computers.

Comment: @fedorqui your hint is useful for sure. date is a very good example to show the magic of linux. "next year", "next monday", "last friday", "+200 day", "-200 day"...  I guess OP made the 1900 just as example.  I am not 100% sure, the cause of 1900 working on your box, not here. but 1970-1900 is > 2^31 (I know the expression is not correct, but you know what I mean). same as if I do a `date -d'3000-01-01'` I got error too.

Comment: @Kent Also see [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Comment: It is funny because I don't get an error even on `$ date -d'90000001-1-1'
Mon Jan  1 00:00:00 CET 90000001`! Just on `$ date -d'9000000001-1-1 '
Sun Jan  1 00:00:00 CET 410065409` start a strange behaviour and even more on `$ date -d'90000000001-1-1 '
Tue Jan  1 00:00:00 LMT -194313215`.

Answer (score 3):

There's one [standard Unix utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cal.html) that has all the date magic from September 14, 1752 through December 31, 9999 built-in: the calendar `cal`. Instead of reinventing the wheel and do messy date calculations we will use its intelligence to our advantage. The basic problem is: **given a date, is it the last day of a month?** If not, simply increment the day. If yes, reset day to 1 and increment month (and possibly year).

However, the output of `cal` is unspecified and it may look like this:

```
$ cal 2 1900
   February 1900
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28
```

What we would need is a list of days, 1 2 3 ... 28. We can do this by skipping everything up to the "1":

```
 set -- $(cal 2 1900)
 while test $1 != 1; do shift; done
```

Now the number of args gives us the number of days in February 1900:

```
 $ echo $#
 28
```

Putting it all together in a script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

read -r header
printf "%s\n" "$header"

while IFS=,- read -r col1 col2 y m d; do
  case $m-$d in
    (12-31) y=$((y+1)) m=01 d=01;;
    (*)
      set -- $(cal $m $y)
      # Shift away the month and weekday names.
      while test $1 != 1; do shift; done
      # Is the day the last day of a month?
      if test ${d#0} -eq $#; then
        # Yes: increment m and reset d=01.
        m=$(printf %02d $((${m#0}+1)))
        d=01
      else
        # No: increment d.
        d=$(printf %02d $((${d#0}+1)))
      fi
    ;;
  esac
  printf "%s,%s,%s-%s-%s\n" "$col1" "$col2" $y $m $d
done
```

Running it on this input:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
ABC,001,1900-01-01
ABC,001,1900-02-28
ABC,001,1900-12-31
XYZ,002,2000-01-01
XYZ,002,2000-02-28
XYZ,002,2000-02-29
```

yields

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
ABC,001,1900-01-02
ABC,001,1900-03-01
ABC,001,1901-01-01
XYZ,002,2000-01-02
XYZ,002,2000-02-29
XYZ,002,2000-03-01
```

I made one little assumption: The first two columns don't contain a `-` or escaped comma. If they do, the `IFS=,- read` will act up.

Comment: You're welcome. The next step would be to accept this answer by clicking the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `date` command, this can be done in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{("date -d\""$3" +1 day\" +%Y-%m-%d")|getline newdate; $3=newdate; print}' file.in
```

Comment: Dosn't work here. Your date `-d` option is non-standard. A GNUism?

Answer (score 0):

If you can extract the date from the file, you can use this:

```
d="1900-01-01"  # date from file
date --date '@'$(( $(date --date $d +"%s") + 86400 ))
```

Comment: This also requires a non-standard date utility with GNUisms (and prints something not looking like YYYY-MM-dd).